# How to support both @Binding<Value> and @Binding<Value?> in a single view?

Tags: swiftui

I have two components that I would like to merge together.

The first one has `@Binding<Value>` and the second one has `@Binding<Value?>`, where `Value` is a generic type.

Is there a way to combine the two components into one?

Currently I have to create two separate components to achieve what I want...

e.g.

```
public struct ExampleEnumField<Value: EnumFieldValue>: View {
    public init(value: Binding<Value>) {
        self._value = value
    }
    
    @Binding private var value: Value
    
    public var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $value) {
            ForEach(Value.allCases) { value in
                Text(value.localizedString)
                    .tag(value)
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct ExampleOptionalEnumField<Value: EnumFieldValue>: View {
    public init(value: Binding<Value?>) {
        self._value = value
    }
    
    @Binding private var value: Value?
    
    public var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $value) {
            Text("None")
                .tag(nil as Value?)
            ForEach(Value.allCases) { value in
                Text(value.localizedString)
                    .tag(value as Value?)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but you have to provide a `default` value for one if the `init`

```
public struct ExampleEnumField1<Value>: View where Value: CaseIterable & CustomStringConvertible & Hashable {
    @Binding private var value: Value
    
    public init(value: Binding<Value>) {
        self._value = value
    }
    public init(value: Binding<Value?>, default: Value) {
        self._value = .init(get: {
            //If the value is `nil` show de default
            value.wrappedValue ?? `default`
        }, set: { newValue in
            value.wrappedValue = newValue
        })
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $value) {
            ForEach(Array(Value.allCases), id:\.description) { val in
                Text(val.description).tag(val)
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct ExampleEnumField2<Value>: View where Value: CaseIterable & CustomStringConvertible & Hashable {
    typealias V = Value?
    @Binding private var value: V
    
    public init(value: Binding<Value>, default: Value) {
        self._value = .init(get: {
            value.wrappedValue
        }, set: { newValue in
            //Return default if the user picks nil
            value.wrappedValue = newValue ?? `default`
        })
    }
    public init(value: Binding<Value?>) {
        self._value = value
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $value) {
            ForEach(Array(Value.allCases), id:\.description) { val in
                Text("None")
                    .tag(nil as V)
                Text(val.description).tag(val as V)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The decision is purely based on if the default should be presented based on the original value or what the user picks.

Since you have a protocol you can add the `default` to it so you don't have to pass as an argument.

```
public protocol EnumFieldValue: CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible, Hashable{
    static var `default`: Self { get }
}
```

Then simplify a little by using that version.

```
public struct ExampleEnumField2<Value>: View where Value: EnumFieldValue {
    typealias V = Value?
    @Binding private var value: V
    
    public init(value: Binding<Value>) {
        self._value = .init(get: {
            value.wrappedValue
        }, set: { newValue in
            value.wrappedValue = newValue ?? Value.default
        })
    }
    public init(value: Binding<Value?>) {
        self._value = value
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $value) {
            ForEach(Array(Value.allCases), id:\.description) { val in
                Text("None")
                    .tag(nil as V)
                Text(val.description).tag(val as V)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also "protect" the non-optional with a `Bool` but I think the code starts getting messy and UX might be affected.

```
public struct ExampleEnumField2<Value>: View where Value: CaseIterable & CustomStringConvertible & Hashable {
    typealias V = Value?
    @Binding private var value: V
    let showNil: Bool
    public init(value: Binding<Value>) {
        self._value = .init(get: {
            value.wrappedValue
        }, set: { newValue in
            if let newValue = newValue{
                value.wrappedValue = newValue
            }else{
                //fallthrough
                print("ERROR: user picked nil")
            }
        })
        self.showNil = false
    }
    public init(value: Binding<Value?>) {
        self._value = value
        self.showNil = true
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $value) {
            ForEach(Array(Value.allCases), id:\.description) { val in
                if showNil{
                    Text("None")
                    .tag(nil as V)
                }
                Text(val.description).tag(val as V)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2, the caller can convert from optional to non-optional easily, e.g.

`ExampleEnumField(value: Binding($optional))`